# I am getting : “Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module”

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

***Hi everyone I trying to build a small app, but unfortunatly at the end I getting this error below. I have look others topics here but it is not quit the same as mine. What can I do to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.***

```
import express from "express";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
const app = express();
const meals = JSON.parse(readFileSync(__dirname + "/data/meals.json"));
const reviews = JSON.parse(readFileSync(__dirname + "/data/reviews.json"));
const reservations = JSON.parse(
  readFileSync(__dirname + "/data/reservations.json")
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Can't find that one"));

///=== Respond with the json for all the meals For each meal,
//=== if there are reviews matching it's meal ID

app.get("/meals", (req, res, next) => {
  meals.forEach(meal => {
    meal.reviews = [];
    for (let review of reviews) {
      if (meal.id === review.mealId) {
        meal.reviews.push(review);
      }
    }
  });
  res.json(meals);
  next();
});

//==== Respond with the json for all the meals (including it's reviews) that are cheap ====

app.get("/cheap-meals", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(filter(meal => meal.price <= 64));
  next();
});

//=== Respond with the json for all the meals (including it's reviews) that can fit lots of people

app.get("/large-meals", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(filter(meal => meal.maxNumberOfGuests >= 10));
  next();
});

//==== Respond with the json for all reservations ====

app.get("/reservations", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(reservations);
  next();
});

//==== Respond with the json for a random reservation ====

app.get("/reservation", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(reservations[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)]);
  next();
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Magic happens on port " + 8080));
```

***These codes below work, I want to do it with the snippet above.***

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const meals = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/data/meals.json"));
const reviews = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/data/reviews.json"));
const reservations = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/data/reservations.json")
);
```

Comment: seems pretty straightforward of an error: you're using `import` which is reserved for ES modules. Since Node will only consider files with the `.mjs` extension valid modules: did you remember to use the correct file extension? Having said that: mixing `import` and `require` is pretty gross: either stick with Node's `require` or go full ES module, but doing both is pretty weird.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If get you what you said I just have to change my index.js to index.mjs?

Comment: That's one option - give https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_introduction a thorough read-through to understand what Node expects you to do, and what your options are.

Comment: ok, thanks for that

Comment: What’s the specific benefit of import over require that you are seeking in your node application?

Comment: I am new in programming and I want to lear as much as I can. These things are new for me and I need to understand how they work.